# How to adjust the paralleled distance among the points in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a long table as data frame:

```
date         group       value
02-01        A1          0.1
02-01        A1          0.05
02-02        A1          0.02
....
02-01        A2          -0.1
02-01        A2          0.02
...
02-01        A25         0.01
...
```

As you see, there are totally `25` groups, and each has many zeros values. Now I have three demands to plot a multiple graph(each group for one) with value as x-axis and date as y-axis:

1. Zero values are filtered when plotting the graph.
2. The points are shown at the order of time, but never at the same vertical line, even they are in the same day.
3. The distance(paralleled) of points are equal. Avoiding the case that some points are very close while other aren't.

I have tried this method:

```
ggplot(df%>%filter(value != 0.0), aes(x= row.names(df%>%filter(value != 0.0)),y = value)) + geom_line() +facet_wrap(~group)
```

But got `geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?` warning and a empty graph. Could you help me with this problem? Thanks!

EDIT:

Now i have filtered the zeros values, and add a index inside the date frame to make it continuous:

```
date         group       value   index
02-01        A1          0.1     1
02-01        A1          0.0     2
02-02        A1          0.0     3
....
02-01        A2          -0.1    1
02-02        A2          0.0     2
...
02-01        A25         0.0     1
...
```

And then I tried:

```
ggplot(df_filter, aes(x= index,y = value, color = date)) + geom_point() +facet_wrap(~group)
```

However, what i got is:

[image]

It is quite hard to see the trend of `value` in different `group`. How can I adjust the range of `x-axis` of different plot to show it clearly? 
Besides, Why the color is all gray while I set it equal to `date`, so suppose the points in same day should have same color.
Thanks.

Comment: Start by doing the filtering outside the ggplot call. Why are you using the `row.names` and not the dates? If you want to plot a line for each `group` use `group = group` inside `aes()`.

Comment: @Axeman Please take a look at my update

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `+ facet_wrap(scales = 'free')` or `+ facet_wrap(scales = 'free_x')`?

Comment: @Axeman Absolutely! But what about the color? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the color:

```
ggplot(df_filter, aes(x= index,y = value, color = as.character(date)) + geom_point() +facet_wrap(~group)
```